# Writing Video to File with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, video

Hi im trying to write a video from my webcam to my computer but I keep getting the error that my writer isnt opened. Im using windows 8 64 bit, VS 2013 & OpenCV 2.4.10. Here is the code that I am using:

```
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

string intToString(int number){


    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << number;
    return ss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0

    VideoWriter writer;

    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "ERROR INITIALIZING VIDEO CAPTURE" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    char* windowName = "Webcam Feed";
    namedWindow(windowName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window to display our webcam feed

    string filename = "C:\\thevideo.avi";
    int fcc = CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3');
    double fps = 20;
    cv::Size frameSize(cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    writer = VideoWriter(filename, fcc, fps, frameSize);

    if (!writer.isOpened())
    {

        cout << "the writer isnt opened" << endl;
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }




    while (1) {
        Mat frame;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from camera feed

        if (!bSuccess) //test if frame successfully read
        {
            cout << "ERROR READING FRAME FROM CAMERA FEED" << endl;
            break;
        }

        writer.write(frame);

        imshow(windowName, frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

        //listen for 10ms for a key to be pressed
        switch (waitKey(10)){

        case 27:
            //'esc' has been pressed (ASCII value for 'esc' is 27)
            //exit program.
            return 0;

        }


    }

    return 0;

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the use a bit confusing. You do:

```
VideoWriter writer;
```

and then

```
writer = VideoWriter(filename, fcc, fps, frameSize);
```

Either do:

```
VideoWriter writer = VideoWriter(filename, fcc, fps, frameSize);
```

or

```
VideoWriter writer;
writer.open(filename, 0, fps, frameSize, 1);
```

Perhaps that is the issue?

Also, in writer.open(), the last parameter sis the colour setting. Set it accordingly. I have assumed you have colour input.

Also, a more complicated thing could be codec issue. I read that OPENCV can only write AVI files. So, I am not sure if it can use the DIV3 codec for writing. Call the writer with:

```
writer = VideoWriter(filename, -1, fps, frameSize);
```

and see what codecs can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codec:

> int fcc = CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')

instead of:

> int fcc = CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3');